# Refactor if statement with many or

Tags: php, if-statement, refactoring

How to refactor this conditions to make simpler and cleaner? Logic is completely different for each if.

```
if(in_array($sides, [self::ALL_SIDES, self::HORIZONTAL_SIDES, self::TOP_SIDE])) {
    //do a()
}

if(in_array($sides, [self::ALL_SIDES, self::HORIZONTAL_SIDES, self::BOTTOM_SIDE])) {
    //do b()
}

if(in_array($sides, [self::ALL_SIDES, self::VERTICAL_SIDES, self::LEFT_SIDE])) {
    //do c()
}

if(in_array($sides, [self::ALL_SIDES, self::VERTICAL_SIDES, self::RIGHT_SIDE ])) {
    //do d()
}
```

Comment: What is your conditional logic inside each `if` condition? Is it identical? Also, what is `$sides`? There's not enough information here to answer this question. It also belongs on [**StackExchange's CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Age Logic is different for each if.

Comment: @ObsidianAge What kind of information could I also provide to help you with answer?

Comment: this is one of the occations where nested ifs are more readable (and the `in_array` makes it even worse readable)

Comment: @Jeff Could you provide your variant in answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test
{
    const TOP_SIDE = 'a';
    const BOTTOM_SIDE = 'b';
    const HORIZONTAL_SIDES = self::TOP_SIDE . self::BOTTOM_SIDE;

    const LEFT_SIDE = 'c';
    const RIGHT_SIDE = 'd';
    const VERTICAL_SIDES = self::LEFT_SIDE . self::RIGHT_SIDE;

    const ALL_SIDES = self::HORIZONTAL_SIDES . self::VERTICAL_SIDES;


    public function makeTest($sideType)
    {
        if($this->containsSide($sideType, self::TOP_SIDE)) {
            echo 'a';
        }

        if($this->containsSide($sideType, self::BOTTOM_SIDE)) {
            echo 'b';
        }

        if($this->containsSide($sideType, self::LEFT_SIDE)) {
            echo 'c';
        }

        if($this->containsSide($sideType, self::RIGHT_SIDE)) {
            echo 'd';
        }
    }

    private function containsSide($sideType, $singleSide)
    {
        return false !== strpos($sideType, $singleSide);
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->makeTest(Test::ALL_SIDES);
```

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dc9h-1r7i)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$dos =($sides === self::TOP_SIDE)        ? ['a'] : (
      ($sides === self::BOTTOM_SIDE)     ?     ['b'] : (
      ($sides === self::LEFT_SIDE)       ?         ['c'] : (
      ($sides === self::RIGHT_SIDE)      ?             ['d'] : (
      ($sides === self::HORIZONTAL_SIDES)? ['a','b'] : (
      ($sides === self::VERTICAL_SIDES)  ?         ['c','d'] : (
      ($sides === self::ALL_SIDES)       ? ['a','b','c','d']))))));

foreach($dos as $do) $do();
```

Comment: @Aboalnaga What about `ALL_SIDES`, `VERTICAL_SIDES` and `HORIZONTAL_SIDES`?

Comment: sorry didn't get it the first time, did you want the four blocks executed when  `ALL_SIDES` and two if `VERTICAL_SIDES` or HORIZONTAL_SIDES and only one when others

Comment: Yes, just like in example.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is one of the occasions where nested ifs are more readable. This is just one way for this situation, might not be the best suited for other situations.

```
if ($sides==self::ALL_SIDES) {
    // do stuff, that (nearly) always should apply

    if ($sides==self::HORIZONATAL_SIDES) {
          // do stuff that applies to all horizontal sides
          if ($sides==self::TOP_SIDE) {
               // do top-stuff
          } elseif ($sides==self::BOTTOM_SIDE)  {
               // do other stuff
          }
    }
    // copy & adjust the same for vertical...
} else {
   // oops, an error!
}
```

Comment: But logic is completely different for each `if`.

Comment: that depends on what you wanna do in each case (and if some things repeat)

Comment: What do you think about my variant in answers? Does he have flaws?

Comment: I doubt this `const HORIZONTAL_SIDES = self::TOP_SIDE . self::BOTTOM_SIDE;` is even possible! and strpos is for sure not the fastest variant

Comment: what is the possible input for $singleside? And what is the usecase?

Comment: `$singleside` in `makeTest()` was a mistake

Comment: Naming of constant based on another constant working since 5.6.0. Updated answer with using example. You can copy and run code.

Comment: Why `strpos` is not  not the fastest? This is fastest way to check occurrence in string (function written in `C`) and it operating with constants and string of max of 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is always calling a function, you can create an associative array that maps each of the different values to the corresponding function.

```
$vertical_side_map = [
    self::LEFT_SIDE => 'c',
    self::RIGHT_SIDE => 'd'
];

foreach ($vertical_side_map as $key => $func) {
    if(in_array($sides, [self::ALL_SIDES, self::VERTICAL_SIDES, $key])) {
        $func();
    }
}


$horizontal_side_map = [
    self::TOP_SIDE => 'a',
    self::BOTTOM_SIDE => 'b',
];

foreach ($horizontal_side_map as $key => $func) {
    if(in_array($sides, [self::ALL_SIDES, self::HORIZONTAL_SIDES, $key])) {
        $func();
    }
}
```